# Android: Arranging database list ascending and descending

Tags: android, list

Im doing a bit of code to arrange contacts in different orders, to place them in ascending order would be adding  --> + " ASC"  on the end.

What would you use to have a list aescending?  DSC? or is there another sorthand or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DESC will sort your query in descending order.